# How to ignore the leading zeros in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

While using the query:

```
select c_name from country where c_code_numeric='004';
```

it returns the correct result.

But with this:

```
select c_name from country where c_code_numeric='4';
```

returns an empty result

My questions are

- Why is it so?
- How to avoid this?

`c_code_numeric` is VARChar.

This one works fine for me in both cases of 004 or just 4:

```
select c_name from country where c_code_numeric +0='4';
```

Comment: Why not ignore the zeros and store the code as INT?

Answer (score 2):

If c_code_numeric is a VARCHAR that contains a number, you could use this query:

```
SELECT c_name
FROM country
WHERE c_code_numeric=4
```

that will cast c_code_numeric to a number, or you might also want to try this:

```
SELECT c_name
FROM country
WHERE c_code_numeric+0=4
```

Comment: How this looks like to mysql?

Comment: c_code_numeric is a varchar but using the query u answered it returns empty result

Comment: its working good your previous ans :
:)
 select c_name from country where c_code_numeric +0='4'

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql cast function to explicit [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

```
select c_name from country where CAST(c_code_numeric AS UNSIGNED) = 4
```

Comment: can u just type the full query for mycase?

Comment: @aqkhan `select c_name from country where CAST(c_code_numeric AS UNSIGNED) = 4`

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend leading zero with `LPAD`

```
SELECT c_name FROM country WHERE c_code_numeric = LPAD('4', 3, '0')
```

#### Usage

```
LPAD(value, lenght, start_with)
```

#### Examples:

```
LPAD('4', 3, '0')   // 004
LPAD('14', 3, '0')  // 014
LPAD('114', 3, '0') // 114
```